# OpenGL track minimum distance points between a pair of 3D lines

Tags: opengl, 3d, geometry, pyopengl

I am trying to execute the following in OpenGL: There are 2 3D points p1 and p2, let's say at positions (-1,0,0) and (1,0,0). A 3D line is drawn through both points. Let's say the direction vectors for both the lines are (0,0,1) to begin with. I want to track the points of minimum distance between the two lines and display them as these lines are rotated about the points p1 and p2 about random axes by small angles.

I am new to OpenGL and quite confused about where the computation of nearest points between lines should be carried out. If I draw the two lines by providing end points, I cannot do the computation in the geometry shader as it only has access to one primitive, while I need both lines to calculate the closest points.

How should I proceed with this?

Comment: This isn't really a job for OpenGL or a shader. Do the computation on the CPU side (where you know everything) and just draw the result. OpenGL is a graphics API, not a math framework.

Comment: Hi @NicoSchertler ! Thanks for the response. As far as I understand, the rotation to the lines is applied inside the vertex shader, so I do not know the positions of both the lines' end points before that. Would you suggest doing everything including the rotations and closest point computations before sending to the shaders ?

Comment: As in most cases, there are a multitude of possible solutions. Yes, you could do everything on the GPU in a shader. That would require tricking OpenGL a bit, but it is possible (e.g., feeding GL_LINES_ADJACENCY into the geometry shader, which gives you 4 vertices). But it also requires you to re-calculate the point in every frame. Or you do it on the CPU side (i.e. including the transformation) and upload the point for the GPU to draw. You can still use the vertex shader to transform the vertices. You would, however, do this in two places (CPU and GPU). This is not too bad, though.